# Do the Shayateen know Allah is real?

Tags: allah, shaitan, jinn

The first Shaitan (Iblis) knows Allah is real and makes humans and jinns disbelieve in Allah. When we say verses like Ayatul Kursi, the shayateen will go away from our house for a couple of days. If they know why they can't enter our houses when we say verses like Ayatul Kursi, do they know Allah is real? If so why do the choose to not and can they become Muslim jinn?

Comment: Nice question, but it's answer will be no short one

Comment: Devils don't make humans disbelieve, the have no authority to do so, rather they advice us to disbelieve!

Comment: I don't think the shayteen go away for 2 days for just the aayatul kursi, but they do go away for 3 days in a house where surah baqara is recited. I was thinking of a similar thing once, why do magician not believe in the unseen when they make contracts with jinns; it is key in magic to do act that displease God and you fight magic with the Quran

Answer (score -1):

The Shayateen (devils or demons) are creatures created by Allah (God) from smokeless flame, just like angels and humans. They are considered to be disobedient to Allah and to actively seek to misguide and mislead human beings from the path of righteousness.

The Quran mentions that the Shayateen are aware of Allah's existence and power, and that they recognize Him as their Creator and Lord. However, they have chosen to rebel against Him and to lead human beings astray from the path of righteousness. In the Quran, Allah says:

"Indeed, Satan is an enemy to you; so take him as an enemy. He only invites his party to be among the companions of the Blaze. Those who disbelieve in the verses of Allah will have a severe punishment" (Quran 35:6-7)

The Quran also mentions that the Shayateen will be held accountable for their actions on the Day of Judgment, just like human beings. In one verse, Allah says:

"And [mention, O Muhammad], the Day when We will gather them all together - then We will say to those who associated others with Allah, 'Where are your 'partners' that you used to claim [with Him]?' Then there will be no [excuse upon] examination except they will say, 'By Allah, our Lord, we were not those who associated.'" (Quran 6:22-23)

Therefore, according to Islamic belief, the Shayateen are aware of Allah's existence and power, but they have chosen to reject His authority and guidance. They will be held accountable for their actions on the Day of Judgment, just like human beings.